# Why doesn't "sich Mühe geben" require "um" while "Mühe auf sich nehmen" does?

Tags: conjunction

> Er hat sich alle **Mühe** gegeben, es sie glauben zu lassen.
>
> {vs}: ... Deshalb haben wir doch diese ganze **Mühe** auf uns genommen, **um** es zu bekommen.

Both sentences are about going out of your way to achieve something, and with the "*sich Mühe geben*" construction, I have never seen *um* placed at the top of the "*to achieve something*" part.

So I kind of automatically assumed that *Mühe* and *um* shouldn't go together when *Mühe* is used with this specific meaning. Then I came across the second construction "*Mühe auf sich nehmen*" which is followed this time by *um*.

Which now makes me wonder why the "*sich Mühe geben*" construction does not require *um* to express the idea of "*in order to*" in the first place. I cannot seem to  recall another instance where you are allowed to omit *um* with the "*in order to*" meaning.

Comment: It doesn't require it. "Er hat sich alle Mühe gegeben, um es sie glauben zu lassen" also works, as does "Mühe auf uns genommen, es zu bekommen", but both have slightly different meaning than the resp. other variant, and the original variants are more natural in this particular context.

Comment: With ''um'' you can tell a reason why you do/did something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me, the difference seems about whether you make an effort *of doing something*, or whether you make an effort *in order to achieve something*. The latter goes with "um ... zu".

#### First sentence

Let's compare:

> (1) Er hat sich alle Mühe gegeben, es sie glauben zu lassen.
>
> (2) Er hat sich alle Mühe gegeben, **um** es sie glauben zu lassen.

Both wordings are possible, though there is a difference in what they literally express. The first one expresses that he made all efforts to make her believe (i.e., he made only those efforts that are suited to make her believe). The second one expresses that he made *all efforts* (no restriction), and did that with the aim of making her believe. The difference may be rather nuanced and tends to be overheard, but it would explain why the first sentence is more natural.

It also explains the possibility of reordering. While this one is possible (though a bit construed, because "Mühe (ge)geben" belong together):

> (1') Er hat sich alle Mühe, es sie glauben zu lassen, gegeben.

this one is awkward:

> (2') *Er hat sich alle Mühe, **um** es sie glauben zu lassen, gegeben.

#### Second sentence

Again, let's compare:

> (3) Deshalb haben wir doch diese ganze Mühe auf uns genommen, es zu bekommen.
>
> (4) Deshalb haben wir doch diese ganze Mühe auf uns genommen, **um** es zu bekommen.

Sentence (3) expresses that this is why we made all the efforts of getting X. This requires that the *reason* (what "Deshalb" refers to) has already been mentioned or is contextually salient.

Sentence (4) expresses that we made all those efforts ("*diese* ganze Mühe"), and we did it in order to get X. This requires that the *efforts* have already been mentioned or are contextually salient. It does not require that any reason has been mentioned yet, because the sentence *is giving* a reason ("Deshalb ..., um ... zu ...")

Hence, I think that depending on the context, *both* sentences are possible. That said, I find the reordered

> (3') Deshalb haben wir doch diese ganze Mühe, es zu bekommen, auf uns genommen.

more natural than (3). "aus uns genommen" seems a bit wide a stretch in this case...

Answer (score 1):

Here, the question should not actually be about **sich Mühe geben** or **Mühe auf sich nehmen**.

The actual question shall be

**When should be used *um ... zu* and when only *zu*?**

An example with *um ... zu*

> Er geht zum Arzt, um gesund zu werden -> He goes to the Doctor in order to get well

and an example with only *zu*

> Die Spinne versucht sich zu verstecken -> The spider tries (himself) to hide

The first example of yours is constructed with only *zu*, while the second one with *um ... zu*. These are not same but similar to the English version of only *to* and *in order to*.

There is a very good [tutorial](https://yourdailygerman.com/2012/03/01/use-of-zu-and-um-zu/), which shows the differences between *um ... zu* with *zu*.

Comment: And why don't you answer the actual question? :-)

Comment: @dirkt after 30 seconds of your comment, the edit is already done :)

Comment: Interesting! So does "um" serve to emphasise the "in order to" aspect?

Comment: @Alone-zee As I stated in my answer, these structures are not 100% same but very similar. I have added a tutorial to the end of my answer. Please, read it. It explains very good the differences between these structures.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the difference between *um zu* and *zu*, maybe also have a look at examples for [final](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Adverbial/Final.html?lang=en) and [consecutive](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Adverbial/Konsekutiv.html?lang=en) use of *um zu*, as compared to the purely [subordinating](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Form/Infinitiv.html) use of *zu*.

Comment: Yes, I know, it's not a good answer according to stackexchange criteria, but it gets very long if I just copy everything there, and I think it will still be useful for the one asking.